# Cannot access server shares via VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, network-share

I have set up a my server to accept VPN connections. My users primarily use VPN to access the server shares files.  Everything was working fine until one day I was doing some work on the file system and all of a sudden all of my users cannot access the server shares.

I know the VPN connection is OK because I can ping several devices on the remote network through the VPN connection. Local users are not having any problems accessing the server shares locally.

Whenever I try to access the server shares through the VPN I get an error message:

> The folder you entered does not appear to be valid.  Please choose another.

The path I am using is:

```
\\pbpmwinserver01\server shares
```

Obviously I have messed up something but I am not sure what I did.  I am thinking it is some sort of group permissions problem but I have checked and all seems OK as well as I understand the correct profiles.

How can I go about debugging the problem further?

Comment: Do you have webdav sharE ?

Comment: You neglect to mention what you're using as a VPN termination point.

Comment: How many subnets do you have on your network? We had a similar problem when we added a new subnet to our network.

Comment: Can you ping the hostname? Is your vpn client seeing the domain?

Comment: Do you really have a blank in the share name?

Comment: Try to browse the share of the server by going to `\\server`

Comment: Is the VPN server the same as the file server? Are they on the same network? Do you have any firewalls in place? Do you have any routing rules in place that would prevent remote devices from communicating with this server? Are remote devices able to access any other local resources on the network?  Can you access the server pbpmwinserver01 in any way (if so, what service/protocol)?  Assuming the file server is a Windows Server, can you access the root share (C$, D$, E$, etc..), using local/domain admin credentials?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a firewall rule on the file server that restricts access based on IP. I'm assuming that your VPN clients are assigned a different IP than your internal clients. You should check the scope definition for the `File & Print Services (SMB-IN)` rule if you're using Windows 2008 or 2008 R2 on the file server.

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 as my VPN termination point.  When I remotely desktop connection into the server I can see that the VPN client connection is successful.  I am using statically assigned ip addresses for VPN clients.  I checked my server share properties and everything looks ok.  I checked the firewall properties and they are ok too.  I turned off the firewall but still could not accessedmthe shared files.  The error I get is "Windows cannot access "\\pbpmwinserver01\server shares" In the details I get "Error code 0x80070035, The networkd path was not found".

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the local firewall or antivirus software is not blocking the connection. Disable Norton or McAfee to see if you can connect to the share.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions that may help debugging the problem:

- Check if it works if you enclose the path in quotes `"\\pbpmwinserver01\server shares"`
- Check that the share it is accessing is `"\\pbpmwinserver01\server"` (without quotes).
- If the share paths are fine my next thought would be to validate the VPN (can you ping the server, can you resolve the IP of the hostname, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

First you need to make sure there is nothing wrong with the shares. Try to access them within your network and make sure they are working the way you want to. Use one of your users account having the problem connecting with VPN to make sure is not a user account relates issue neither.

You need to be systematic when troubleshooting problems.

If everything works within your network then VPN is the issue. VPNs connections are complicated and hard to troubleshoot.

Having multiple subnets and using the remote routing component in Windows creates a routing problem.. Computers connecting to the VPN  using the same subnet won't be able to get to the network...because of the routing problem.